# Save List of IP that are hitting url

Tags: java, jsp, data-structures

I wanted to ask that If I have an application running on server which can be accessed by a given URL, how may I save the list of IP addresses hitting that URL.

Technologies that I am using are java, jsp etc.

I need a global data-structure to avoid the need of using database.

I am able to get the current IP hitting the URL. The problem is, when ever a new IP hits the application, the application runs from the beginning, which flushes the previous values in DS(Since the DS is an Object, every time application runs, the object is re-initialized).

I tried to search for examples on net but could not. Can anyone suggest what may be done to sort this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, your application server already does this out-of-the-box in their logfiles. All you need is a proper log-parser.

Comment: Hey @Roist, I have seen the IP are reflected in the logfiles, but I do not know how to use a log parser to enlist all the IP addresses together. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the information within the webapp itself, then you can store the data structure as a [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) attribute.

But be careful.  This will be an (effectively) global data structure, and could turn into a memory leak if there is nothing to remove "old" or "stale" entries from the data structure.

Comment: Hey @Stephen, I totally agree with you. I have a session of 15 minutes to lock a particular IP, so I think I'll handle the removal of old entries as soon as their particular session is closed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You knew ip address (request.getRemoteAddr ()) of the machine hitting your url.

1. If you need a simpler solution, save that ip in File.

OR

2. Save it in one of NoSQL databases.

OR

3. Save it in in - memory database like Redis/Berkley/CouchDB and persist it to Nosql or file system on need basis.

Comment: Hey @Ravindra : I had thought of saving the entries in a file, but the overhead in writing and reading and "removing" the stale entries would be much more. And regarding the db, I have to entirely avoid using any sort of db, I need to save the values in the application itself. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In - memory database with disk persistence is the solution you may be interested

Comment: If you don't need reliability and high availability, just store in memory. Restart of Web server don't have any info in this case. If you need reliability, persist the info.